# def Accessing file from different script

Tags: python

Firstly, the directory.

```
file1.py
|
| --__init__.py 
    file2.py
    some_package
    |
    | --__init__.py
        config.py
        settings.ini
    other_package
    |
    | --__init__.py 
        access.py
```

Now, in `config.py`, there's a function, `readfromsetting()`, which reads `settings.ini` and returns the content inside. In `access.py`, i've imported `config.py` (No, it's not what you're thinking, `access.py` successfully imports `config.py`), and tried calling `readfromsetting()` function, but Python throws error.

`No such file or directory, "settings.ini"`

So, my question is, how can I read the content of `settings.ini`, from `access.py` using `config.py`?

My `config.py`:

```
def readfromsetting():
    with open('settings.py', 'r') as file:
        return file.read()
```

My `access.py`

```
from some_package import config

def get_setting():
    return config.readfromsetting()
```

Comment: Please provide working code for the important parts of your program (config.py with readfromsetting() and access.py). First guess would be that you use a relative path within readfromsetting() which would not work since your access.py is in another package/directory.

Comment: probably you mean settings.ini and not settings.py in your open call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `import <some script>` python looks inside the contents of `sys.path` to import the python script . But when you are reading files using `open()` or other methods, and you give relative paths, Python would try to resolve the path as relative to the current working directory, it would not look inside the directory in which you script resides (unless that is the working directory).

You should not depend on relative paths, instead you should try giving absolute paths, where possible.

In your case, if you are sure that the directory structure would not change (that is `settings.ini` would always be in the directory in which `config.py` exists or `settings.py` exists) , you can use `__file__` variable to access the path of the file, and then use that to create absolute path to your `settings.ini` . Example -

```
import os.path
dirpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
settings_file = os.path.join(dirpath,'settings.ini')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
def readfromsetting():
  with open('settings.ini', 'r') as file:
    return file.read()
```

'settings.ini' is a relative path. This works perfect if the file your are looking for is in the same directory. Since you call this method from access.py and access.py resides not in this directory, it cannot find the settings.ini file.

I recommend you use instead an absolute path for the settings.ini file in your open method. If you are sure that you only call this method from within access.py, you can also edit `__file__` like mentioned in the other answer.